# For-to-Infinitive clause

Tags: infinitive-clauses

I have the following statement:

> I find it necessary for you to graduate from school.

Though, I can rephrase it:

> I think it best for you to graduate from school.

I read about `"for-to-infinitive clauses"` and suppose my second sentence to be correct. Why should I write `"...it best...`" instead of `"...it is best..."`? It just boils down to the rule: I mean it's so because it's so.

Comment: Think, consider, etc can take a direct object, here "it", followed by an object complement in the form of a predicate adjective ( *Don't you think him strange?*   *Consider it done.* ) or in the form of a nominal (*"Do you think me a  fool, Sir?" he asked indignantly.*  and  *I consider him a friend*).

Comment: Subordinate _to_-infinitival clauses with a subject require the subordinator "for". Both "I think (that) it is best" and the idiomatic "I think it best" are possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I think that it is best that..."

and

> "I think it best that..."

have exactly the same meaning.

---

They are both grammatically correct but saying "I think it best" is more efficient and widely accepted as the preferred option.